# iOS UI testing - presented view controller appearing as "other element"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

I am trying to write UI tests for my app. I have a pop up which is a modally presented view controller with a UITableView on it. The tableview contains 2 clickable cells, both of which dismiss the view controller. The problem is when this pop up appears, it is appearing as an "other element" in my elements tree and not as a view controller. I can find the element with `otherElements[@"PopOverViewController"]` but I am unable to click the cells on the controller as it doesn't know what they are.

```
 →Other 0x7fc778039540: traits: 8589934592, {{32.0, 155.5}, {311.0, 356.0}}, label: 'PopOverViewController'
```

How can I access this element and click the buttons on this view controller?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is the output when the PopOverViewController is showing

```
  Image 0x7fc26378c270: traits: 8589934596
  Image 0x7fc263784310: traits: 8589934596, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 64.0}}
  Button 0x7fc263786ff0: traits: 8724152321, {{8.0, 26.0}, {110.0, 30.0}}, label: '*****'
  Button 0x7fc26378d480: traits: 8724152321, {{8.0, 36.5}, {11.0, 11.0}}, label: '*****'
  StaticText 0x7fc263794620: traits: 8589934656
  StaticText 0x7fc2637817d0: traits: 8590000192
  NavigationBar 0x7fc263788140: traits: 35192962023424, {{0.0, 20.0}, {375.0, 44.0}}, identifier: '*****'
  StaticText 0x7fc263793090: traits: 8589934656, {{146.5, 70.5}, {82.0, 22.0}}, label: '*****'
  Button 0x7fc26378ea40: traits: 8589934593, {{67.5, 104.5}, {240.0, 35.0}}, label: '*****'
  StaticText 0x7fc26378de50: traits: 8589934656, {{86.0, 155.5}, {203.5, 38.5}}, label: '*****'
  Other 0x7fc263795f30: traits: 8589934592, {{67.5, 54.0}, {240.0, 168.0}}
  Other 0x7fc26379b470: traits: 8589934592
  Other 0x7fc26379a570: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 64.0}, {375.0, 148.0}}
  Other 0x7fc26378f9c0: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 216.0}, {375.0, 407.0}}
  StaticText 0x7fc26379be90: traits: 8589934656, {{90.0, 232.0}, {53.5, 20.5}}, label: '*****'
  StaticText 0x7fc26379c4f0: traits: 8589934656, {{90.0, 250.0}, {114.0, 19.5}}, label: '*****'
  StaticText 0x7fc26379cd60: traits: 8589934656, {{90.0, 289.0}, {57.0, 18.0}}, label: '*****'
  Cell 0x7fc2637934c0: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 216.0}, {375.0, 123.0}}
  StaticText 0x7fc26379dc10: traits: 8589934656, {{90.0, 355.0}, {52.5, 20.5}}, label: '*****'
  StaticText 0x7fc26379e330: traits: 8589934656, {{90.0, 373.0}, {98.0, 19.5}}, label: '*****'
  StaticText 0x7fc26379ea80: traits: 8589934656, {{90.0, 412.0}, {57.0, 18.0}}, label: '*****'
  Cell 0x7fc26379d490: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 339.0}, {375.0, 123.0}}
  StaticText 0x7fc26379f970: traits: 8589934656, {{90.0, 478.0}, {95.0, 20.5}}, label: '*****'
  StaticText 0x7fc2637a00b0: traits: 8589934656, {{90.0, 496.0}, {129.5, 19.5}}, label: '*****'
  StaticText 0x7fc2637a0800: traits: 8589934656, {{90.0, 535.0}, {57.0, 18.0}}, label: '*****'
  Cell 0x7fc26379f1f0: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 462.0}, {375.0, 123.0}}
  Table 0x7fc2637901b0: traits: 35192962023424, {{0.0, 64.0}, {375.0, 559.0}}
  Button 0x7fc2637a0ff0: traits: 8589934593, {{0.0, 623.0}, {375.0, 44.0}}, label: '*****'
  Other 0x7fc2637a1710: traits: 8589934592
  Other 0x7fc263796ea0: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 64.0}, {375.0, 603.0}}
  Other 0x7fc263799490: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
  Other 0x7fc263791ac0: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
  Other 0x7fc26376a060: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
  Image 0x7fc2637a26a0: traits: 4, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
  Other 0x7fc2637a2de0: {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
  Other 0x7fc2637a3500: traits: 8589934592, {{32.0, 155.5}, {311.0, 356.0}}, label: 'PopOverViewController'
  Other 0x7fc2637a1f50: {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
  Other 0x7fc263782e40: {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
  Window 0x7fc263112950: Main Window, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
  Other 0x7fc2637a4cc0: traits: 8589934592
  Other 0x7fc2637a44d0: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
  Window 0x7fc2637a3d50: {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
  Other 0x7fc2637a6340: {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 20.0}}
  Other 0x7fc2637a7210: traits: 8388608, {{6.0, 0.0}, {39.0, 20.0}}
  Other 0x7fc2637a7960: traits: 8388608, {{50.0, 0.0}, {13.0, 20.0}}, label: '3 of 3 Wi-Fi bars', value: SSID
  Other 0x7fc2637a80e0: traits: 8389120, {{165.0, 0.0}, {48.0, 20.0}}, label: '1:29 PM'
  Other 0x7fc2637a8850: traits: 8388608, {{345.0, 0.0}, {25.0, 20.0}}, label: '-100% battery power'
  Other 0x7fc2637a6a90: {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 20.0}}
  StatusBar 0x7fc2637a5bd0: {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 20.0}}
  Window 0x7fc2637a5450: {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
```

I can see the PopOverViewController but none of the text or cells on it (text is blanked out but is from the presenting view controller, not what's on the pop over view controller)

**EDIT**

If I run `[app.otherElements[@"PopOverViewController"] descendantsMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeAny]` I see the output:

```
Other 0x7fc263795f30: traits: 8589934592, {{67.5, 54.0}, {240.0, 168.0}}
  Other 0x7fc26379b470: traits: 8589934592
  Other 0x7fc26379a570: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 64.0}, {375.0, 148.0}}
  Other 0x7fc26378f9c0: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 216.0}, {375.0, 407.0}}
  Other 0x7fc2637a1710: traits: 8589934592
  Other 0x7fc263796ea0: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 64.0}, {375.0, 603.0}}
  Other 0x7fc263799490: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
  Other 0x7fc263791ac0: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
  Other 0x7fc26376a060: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
  Other 0x7fc2637a2de0: {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
  Other 0x7fc2637a3500: traits: 8589934592, {{32.0, 155.5}, {311.0, 356.0}}, label: 'PopOverViewController'
  Other 0x7fc2637a1f50: {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
  Other 0x7fc263782e40: {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
  Other 0x7fc2637a4cc0: traits: 8589934592
  Other 0x7fc2637a44d0: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
  Other 0x7fc2637a6340: {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 20.0}}
  Other 0x7fc2637a7210: traits: 8388608, {{6.0, 0.0}, {39.0, 20.0}}
  Other 0x7fc2637a7960: traits: 8388608, {{50.0, 0.0}, {13.0, 20.0}}, label: '3 of 3 Wi-Fi bars', value: SSID
  Other 0x7fc2637a80e0: traits: 8389120, {{165.0, 0.0}, {48.0, 20.0}}, label: '1:29 PM'
  Other 0x7fc2637a8850: traits: 8388608, {{345.0, 0.0}, {25.0, 20.0}}, label: '-100% battery power'
  Other 0x7fc2637a6a90: {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 20.0}}
```

Which could possibly be my presented view controller but I can't see what any of the objects are due to them all being "Other"

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the cell's by content directly.

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
[app.staticTexts[@"Cell One"] tap];
```

Comment: Have tried this and it hasn't helped. When looking through the element inspector, the text on the 2 button's doesn't appear despite them being on the screen. I'm not doing anything special with the view controller, it's a non-full screen modal with custom transition.

Answer (score 0):

Elements inside a container view are usually not accessible. Make the PopOverViewController inaccessible and the cells should become available.

```
self.isAccessibilityElement = false
```

Do this on the view Controller and then query the cells as usual.

```
app.cells.elementBoundByIndex(0).tap()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried this as well as to no avail. I've taken print outputs from the element tree before and after showing the pop up and it doesn't change, the new elements just don't appear in the element tree.

Comment: @IanYakHoughton could you add output to your question of `app.descendantsMatchingType(.Any).debugDescription` for before and after the popup?

Comment: I've added the output to my original question with text blanked out. I can see 'PopOverViewController' but nothing associated to it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by removing the flag for accessibility enabled on the storyboard. After this, the cells became visible in the element inspector.